# submitting a from inside of an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a page in which I have the following iFrame:

```
<iframe src="fileupload.php" id="fup_iframe" style="display: none">
</iframe>
```

fupload.php:

```
<form id="UploadForm" action="up.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="fType" type="hidden" name="ftype" value="" />
    <input id="fName" type="file" name="ffile" style="display: none"/>
</form>
```

I want to submit this form inside a JS from the page where I have the iFrame. I tried the following but didn't work. Can you tell me where the problem is?

```
function startUpload(value) {
    $('#fiframe').contents().find('#fType').attr('value', value);
    $('#fiframe').contents().find('#fName').click();
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery/JavaScript: accessing contents of an iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407276/jquery-iframe-form-submit